# Package natbib: change in-text citation [Johnson 1990] to [Joh1990]

Tags: citing, natbib

I'm using `natbib` and I'd like to change the in-text citation.
If author and year are Johnson 1990 the output should be [Joh1990], I want `natbib` to print the first three letters of the author and the year without space. But I do not know how to set the command to shorten the names.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,parskip,11pt,listof=totoc,bibliography=totoc,openright]{scrbook}
% Kopf- und Fußzeile mit Separationslinie
%\usepackage[automark,footsepline,plainfootsepline,headsepline,plainheadsepline]{scrpage2} 
\usepackage[automark,footsepline,plainfootsepline,headsepline]{scrpage2} 
% Seitenränder einstellen
\usepackage[left=2.5 cm, right=2.5 cm, top=2.5 cm, bottom=3 cm]{geometry}
% Seitenstil definieren
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
% Kapitel bzw. Unterkapitel in Kopfzeile
\automark[section]{chapter} 

% ngerman = Deutsch (bspw. table of contents übersetzen) + neue Rechtschreibung (sonst german)
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
% inputenc = ä,ö,ü wird erkannt % Dokument ist utf8-kodiert, nicht latin wie vorgegeben! 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
% beinhaltet u. a. \usepackage{array} % für Tabellen
\usepackage{amsmath}  
% positioniert die Tabellen (und Bilder?) an den Anfang der chapter (sonst sind sie da, wo Platz ist)
\usepackage[section]{placeins}  
%für Bilder
\usepackage{graphicx}

% Beispieltext
\usepackage{blindtext}

% Zitationsstil laden, Verzeichnisname auf chapter-Ebene setzen (für Inhaltsverzeichnis und Kopfzeile)
\usepackage[sectionbib,square]{natbib}
% Kurzzitatverwendung:
\newcommand{\shortcite}[1]{\cite{#1}} % XXX weiter: gucken was man verändern muss für shortcite in .bib
%Einbindung deutsche Klammern
\usepackage[babel,german=guillemets]{csquotes}
% Abkürzungsverzeichnis
\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym}
%Inkludieren von pdf
\usepackage{pdfpages} % Befehl: \includepdf[pages={5,8,10-14}]{Dokumentname.pdf}
% vollkommen leere Seiten
\usepackage[clearempty]{titlesec}
%Fußnoten durchgängig nummerieren, nicht kapitelweise 
\usepackage{chngcntr} 
\counterwithout{footnote}{chapter}
% \usepackage{hyperref} % klicken und springen
%package glossaries
\usepackage{glossaries}
% alt:  \newglossary[slg]{symbolslist}{syi}{syg}{Symbolverzeichnis}
\newglossary[slg]{symbolslist}{syi}{syg}{Symbolverzeichnis}
% den Punkt am Ende jeder Beschreibung deaktivieren
\renewcommand*{\glspostdescription}{}
% Glossar-Befehle anschalten
\makeglossaries


 \begin{document}


text text text [Vgl. \cite{Wittgruber2002}, S. 131].  % [LLL Wittgruber S. 131]
text text text [Vgl. \cite{Etschberger1994}, S. 1]. \\ % [LLL Etschberger S. 1]. XX hier also: 

\bibliographystyle{natdin}
%\bibliographystyle{natbib}
%Einbinden der BiBTex-Datei "literaturverzeichnis3" (Muss im selben Verzeichnis liegen wie .tex-Datei)- An die Stelle, wo das LV hin soll
% wenn neue Datei: hier F7, dann Ausgabe->BibTex, dann noch 2x F7. Falls es nicht funktioniert Style ändern
\bibliography{literaturverzeichnis3}


 \end{document}


% entries of bib-file literaturverzeichnis3:
%
%@book{Etschberger1994,
 %author = {Etschberger, Konrad},
 %year = {1994},
 %title = {{C}ontroller-{A}rea-{N}etwork ; {G}rundlagen, {P}rotokolle, {B}austeine, {A}nwendungen},
 %address = {M{\"u}nchen [u.a.]},
 %edition = {2},
 %publisher = {Hanser},
 %isbn = {3446175962}
%}
%
%
%@book{Wittgruber2002,
 %author = {Wittgruber, Friedrich},
 %year = {2002},
 %title = {{D}igitale {S}chnittstellen und {B}ussysteme: {E}inf{\"u}hrung f{\"u}r das technische {S}tudium ; mit 8 {T}abellen},
 %address = {Braunschweig and Wiesbaden},
 %edition = {2},
 %publisher = {Vieweg},
 %isbn = {9783528174361},
 %series = {{S}tudium {T}echnik}
%}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You may have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. Add two entries of your `bib` file please ...

Comment: You need to use the `alpha` bibliography style. There are also other variants like `is-alpha`, `amsalpha`, all containing `alpha` in their name.

Comment: I took the liberty of fixing the code formatting in your question. For next time, you can [read the reference on SX flavored markdown syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) =)

Comment: @mafp - Using \bibliographystyle{amsalpha} or alpha doesn´t change nothing. Do I have to adjust other things, too?

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to use the `alpha` bibliography style. This requires to add the `numbers` option to natbib:

```
\usepackage[sectionbib,square,numbers]{natbib}
```

and replacing the bibliography style:

```
\bibliographystyle{alpha}
```

instead of

```
\bibliographystyle{natdin}
```

Then I get:

[image: text output]

[image: bibliography]

Comment: @JannaWilke You are welcome!

Comment: @JannaWilke If it works for you you may also accept the answer (the green tick below the voting buttons).